# How to check if Mongodb enterprise is in use

Tags: mongodb

How to check if mongodb's enterprise version is in use? Is there a flag or property I can query. `mongod --version` only returns the version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From mongo support team, if executing `mongod -h | grep 'snmp-subagent'` does not yield any results, it is likely to be community version (not enterprise).

Comment: can we actually rely on "likely"

Answer (score 24):

I recently asked this question on MongoDB JIRA. Here's reply:

There are at least three ways to discover if you're running Enterprise, I'll leave it to you to determine the easiest for your case:

1) In recent versions of Ops Manager / Cloud Manager a marker is placed after the version number as "-ent". For example, 2.6.11 would be shown as "2.6.11-ent".

2) In a Mongo shell you can check the connected server by running db.serverBuildInfo().gitVersion. Example output on 2.6.9:

```
>db.serverBuildInfo().gitVersion
df313bc75aa94d192330cb92756fc486ea604e64 modules: enterprise
```

Note the "modules: enterprise" is only shown for Enterprise versions.

3) If you have just the binary, you can check the version with the --version flag on the command-line. For example:

```
mongod --version
db version v2.6.9
git version: df313bc75aa94d192330cb92756fc486ea604e64 modules: enterprise
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1m-fips 19 Mar 2015
```

Note the "modules: enterprise" is only shown for Enterprise versions.

Comment: how to change version to enterprise

Answer (score 14):

In MongoDB version 3.6 you can get the information if the enterprise modules have been built or not via mongo shell and the output of

```
db.serverBuildInfo().modules
```

On Enterprise it will state:

```
[ "enterprise" ]
```

On Community an empty array should be shown.

Answer (score 2):

We can get this info from mongod --version,
version:4.0.0 above
for enterprise the modules will be (Enterprise), else it will be null

Enterprise version

[image]

Community version

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Enterprise Edition comes with advance security features such as Kerberos or LDAP as an alternative to password-based or certificate-based authentication and they provide Support and training contract.

If you find anyone of these in your MongoDB then you are using Enterprise Edition.

If you use `db.version()` it will just return the version of the mongod or mongos instance.