# How to ensure if MongoDB is enterprise?

Tags: mongodb

I know there are a lot about this out there and I almost checked all of them. But to my best knowledge, our mongodb is enterprise, but I can't get this info.

I run this command

```
db.serverBuildInfo().modules
```

and it returns `[]` which means it is community version according to [this question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33160352/how-to-check-if-mongodb-enterprise-is-in-use)

Is there any other way to make sure if it's community or enterprise? Thanks very much for help and not unvoting the question in advance! :)

Edit:

MongoDB Version: 4.0.12

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent for the above is (mongo shell):

```
MongoDB Enterprise replset:PRIMARY> db.runCommand({buildInfo:1})["modules"]
[ "enterprise" ]
```

also you may see a prefix `MongoDB Enterprise` (added by the shell).

Additionally, you may check the `bin` folder where server files are placed. Servers after 4.2 will contain `mongocryptd` binary in enterprise version.

Comment: it still returns `[]`. The mongodb version is `4.0.12`. Could be different in this version, just guessing?

Comment: I do not have any Enterprise prefix but not sure if it would be for `4.0.12`